# plot a cluster bar indicator on top of a plot

Tags: matlab

I have a distance matrix of size 2000x2000 which I plot using `imagesc`, the indices is order according to some `time_vec`.

What I want to do is to add some sort of bar indicator of the "clusters" from that vector. Something like what I draw using painter on top of the plot or besides it.

[image]

I don't mind if its below the title or on the side, but I couldn't find a way of doing it on matlab, I don't want to calculate the "clusters" I just want to add them next to the plot. I'm familiar with `clustergram` but it's not what I want because I don't want to change the order

Would appreciate some help

Answer (score 2):

Might something like this work for you?

```
figure
imagesc([rand(100, 100),rand(100,80)+1; rand(80,100)+1,rand(80,80)*.5])
ah = gca;
ah.Clipping = 'off';

lh = line([-10,-10],[0,100]);
lh2 = line([-10,-10],[100,180], 'Color', [0.85, 0.325, 0.098]);

lh.LineWidth = 9;
lh2.LineWidth = 9;
```

[image: example output]